# How to send collectionView data to another ViewController in swift3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uiviewcontroller, collectionview

I want to my collection View data (list.assets_id) want to parse DetailChannel

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        vedioId = id

}
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "detailChannel"{

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DetailsChannel
        destinationVC.vedio_id = vedioId
    }
}
```

In my DetailChannel ,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        debugPrint("DetailsChannel:::::\(vedio_id)")

        if let stringVideo = vedio_id {
            print(stringVideo)
        }
}
```

but didn't work my project and didn't call func prepare().How to slove?

Comment: best way to do this is dependency injection within the initializer, only problem is that Swift and Storybaords are trash, so to explain to you what this means, you wouldn't get it

Comment: Have you added a valid `segue` from the `CollectionViewController` to `DetailChannel`? If so, how did you add it?

Comment: didn't call prepare() and directly go DetailChannel, that's why DetailChannel didn't get data from CollectionViewController. I would like to call prepare() and send data to Next View. I wonder why didn't call prepare @nayem

Comment: Okay. I understood your problem. But tell me, ___how are you going to DetailChannel___? Is it a `segue` that you added by control-dragging from the `CollectionViewCell` to the `DetailChannel`?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess you've added `segue` from `CollectionViewCell` to
>   `DetailChannel`. Delete that `segue`.

Now add a `segue` from your `CollectionViewController` (***not `CollectionViewCell`***) to `DetailChannel`. If you don't know how to add it, here is the process:

1. First control-drag from the `CollectionViewController` to
   `DetailChannel` and let go. [visualize
   here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shbRi.jpg)
2. Then select the `segue` and name it something meaningful to you (in your case *detailChannel*).
   [visualize here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOXVW.jpg)

Now inside your `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method add this line:

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailChannel", sender: self)
```

I hope your `prepare(for:sender:)` is now being called.

Comment: When I added 
performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailChannel", sender: self)
"Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue' happen.

Comment: @SanSan No, it shouldn't. Try writing by yourself. Don't copy-paste from here.